# Conditionally add function as prop in React?

Tags: reactjs

I need to conditionally add a function in React (Native).

This code works but presumably the `onScroll` event is needlessly called when the Platform is web, which I assume is not ideal for performance?

```
  <ScrollView
    onScroll={() => {
      if(Platform.OS === 'web') {
        return;
      }
      container.current?.onScroll();
    }}
  >
```

Is there a way to conditionally set the `onScroll` prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but it's probably more effort than it is worth in terms of performance gains. There is very little cost in calling a function that does nothing.

You can build the props as an object outside of JSX and pass them in using the spread operator, like so:

```
const scrollViewProps = {}

if (Platform.OS !== "web") {
  scrollViewProps.onScroll = () => {
    container.current?.onScroll()
  }
}

<ScrollView {...scrollViewProps} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&&` to create the condition:

```
  <ScrollView
    onScroll={Platform.OS !== 'web' && () => container.current?.onScroll()}
  >
```